# Getting an error while hitting "pulumi up" for aws ec2 ,I am using java

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, pulumi

I have given all unique values in my code, still getting an error, Please anybody help! I am very new to Pulumi and aws.

This is because the value of an 'Output' is asynchronous.

└─ aws:ec2:RouteTableAssociation      publicRouteTableAssociation Calling 'toString' on an 'Output' is not supported.

├─ aws:ec2:Subnet                     publicSubnet1

├─ aws:ec2:RouteTableAssociation      publicRouteTableAssociation Calling 'toString' on an 'Output' is not supported. This is because the value of an 'Output' is asynchronous.

See https://www.pulumi.com/docs/concepts/inputs-outputs for more details. This function may throw in a future version of Pulumi.): error: Duplicate resource URN 'urn:pulumi:Dev::pulumi::aws:ec2/routeTableAssociation:RouteTableAssociation::privateRouteTableAssociation Calling 'toString' on an 'Output' is not supported. This is because the value of an 'Output' is asynchronous.

To get the value of an Output as an Output consider either: 1: applyValue(v -> String.format("prefix%ssuffix", v)) 2: Output.format("prefix%ssuffix", o)

See https://www.pulumi.com/docs/concepts/inputs-outputs for more details. This function may throw in a future version of Pulumi.'; try giving it a unique name.

Here is my Code:

public class App { public static void main(String[] args)

{ Pulumi.run(App::stack); } public static void stack(Context ctx) {

```
var config = ctx.config();
var mainVpc = config.require("vpcCidrBlock");
```

// var region=config.require("aws:region");
var main = new Vpc("main", VpcArgs.builder()
.cidrBlock(mainVpc)
.build());

```
String[] availabilityZones = config.require("availabilityZones").split(",");

// Get the CIDR blocks for subnets from configuration
var publicSubnetCidrBlock = config.require("publicSubnetCidrBlock");
var privateSubnetCidrBlock = config.require("privateSubnetCidrBlock");
```

}}

I tried changing all variable names even though they were unique

Comment: The code's a little hard to read, but I think you may have left out "the good part" -- i.e., the code that's trying to stringify the output. Can you reformat and share more?